# Node / Angular won't load when in-app API calls don't connect

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So, I am using a yo-angular generated node / angular application.

When running the application locally, everything runs as expected, until my application tries to asynchronously load API calls from an outside API endpoint, through my proxy route in express. If those API calls are rejected (perhaps if the endpoint is down, or the endpoint doesn't exist), the overall application stops loading its content.

What would you need to look at to begin identifying this problem?

Here's my proxy code that API calls are passed through:

```
exports.request = function(req, res) {
    var url = req.params[0];
    var _url = req.url;

    var options = {
        host    : 'api.appserver.site.com',
        port    : '8080',
        path    : req.url,
        method  : req.method,
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.rhcm.app-v1.0' 
        }
    };

    var api_request = http.request(options, function(api_response)
    {
        var api_data = "";
        api_response.on('error', function(e) {
          res.status(500).send('Unable to connect to the web service.');
        });
        api_response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            api_data += chunk;
        });
        api_response.on('end', function() {
            try {
                var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(api_data);
                res.json(parsedResponse);
            } catch (e) {
                res.status(500).send('Proxied result returned bad data.');
            }
        });
    });
    api_request.end();
};
```

And when the API is unable to be reached, I get this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

And, if enough bad calls are made to that disabled API, the whole application will stop being served.

However, the page can load just fine if I remove the following portion of that code block: -->

```
var api_request = http.request(options, function(api_response)
{
    ...
});
api_request.end();
```

Edit: I've just found this comment thread on nodejs's repo about a possible memory buildup / failure problem when too many connections happen. It may be the same problem. https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5545

**So, what can I do to ensure that no matter how many API requests are rejected, the actual application itself can still load?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to listen on http events as to catch DNS errors:

```
api_request.on('error', function(err, ...
api_request.end()
```

Better yet, try the request module (https://github.com/request/request) which would handle this and many other issues for you.

Comment: `api_request has no method 'on'` -- is there documentation somewhere that shows that I can catch errors in that way? Also, can you explain how I would be able to pass the http method along to the next request if I were to use the request module?

Comment: I had to rearrange my code, separate out my `http.request(...)` callback function and use it instead as the callback in `api_request.on('connect', function() {})`. Once I did that, I could then write `api_request.on('error', function(error) { ... })`